# How can i use a TFT Screen shield along with other sensors and transmitters

Tags: lcd

I want to use Arduino as described in this instructable:

http://www.instructables.com/id/Uber-Home-Automation-w-Arduino-Pi/

But i thought i would give it a little twist by adding a TFT monitor to some devices. I have bought and got the following tft shield to work:
http://www.banggood.com/UNO-R3-ATmega328P-Board-2_4-Inch-TFT-LCD-Screen-Module-For-Arduino-p-945755.html

But now it strikes me:
How can i combine the screen on an arduino where i also have a sensor and a radio transmitter?

Answer (score 1):

You need another layer! A breadboard shield - from the [same source](http://www.banggood.com/buy/Arduino-breadboard-shield.html) if you like - would seem the obvious answer.
Alternatively, take flying leads from the pins you are using to the screen & mount it elswhere, then connect the sensors.
LCD's use quite a few pins, you'll probably need to be creative with an Uno. I have one on a Mega, & have been there with the same problem!

Comment: Link seems to be incorrect. I think you mean [something like this](http://www.banggood.com/Wholesale-New-Arduino-ProtoShield-Prototype-Kit-Shield-Prototyping-with-Mini-Breadboard-p-42828.html). Also, I don't think there is enough room in between the two shield for an breadboard, and associated wires. Soldering would an a good option here.